# Google wallet is not working Android kotlin

Tags: android, android-pay, google-pay, wallet, wallet-connect

I am trying to create an application like this to save my ticket passes in google wallet https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-android#0. I have done all steps but I couldn't get the result.
[Google pay button is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pn7o.jpg)

Actually, I have a google pay on my mobile but it shows "Unfortunately google pay is not available on this phone" and the google pay button is not visible in the application. so I have manually enabled the google pay button. and when I click that it shows an error "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR_BIBED_07]. how to fix this error.

[Request failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1E9t.jpg)

and this is my code

*that made google pay visible

```
private fun setGooglePayAvailable(available: Boolean) {
    if (available) {
        googlePayButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                R.string.google_pay_status_unavailable,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                googlePayButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }
}
```

*onClick google pay button

```
private fun requestPayment() {

    // Disables the button to prevent multiple clicks.
    googlePayButton.isClickable = false

    // The price provided to the API should include taxes and shipping.
    // This price is not displayed to the user.
    val dummyPriceCents = 100L
    val shippingCostCents = 900L
    val task = model.getLoadPaymentDataTask(dummyPriceCents + shippingCostCents)

    task.addOnCompleteListener { completedTask ->
        if (completedTask.isSuccessful) {
            completedTask.result.let(::handlePaymentSuccess)
        } else {
            when (val exception = completedTask.exception) {
                is ResolvableApiException -> {
                    resolvePaymentForResult.launch(
                        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(exception.resolution).build()
                    )
                }
                is ApiException -> {
                    handleError(exception.statusCode, exception.message)
                }
                else -> {
                    handleError(
                        CommonStatusCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR, "Unexpected non API" +
                                " exception when trying to deliver the task result to an activity!"
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        // Re-enables the Google Pay payment button.
        googlePayButton.isClickable = true
    }
}
```

*my google wallet button

```
private fun setAddToGoogleWalletAvailable(available: Boolean) {
    if (available) {
        layout.passContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            R.string.google_wallet_status_unavailable,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

In the same way, when I enabled the google wallet button. when I click that it's not even responding. it should actually save my passes in google wallet

*OnClick wallet button

```
private fun requestSavePass() {

    // Disables the button to prevent multiple clicks.
    addToGoogleWalletButton.isClickable = false

    model.savePassesJwt(model.genericObjectJwt, this, addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)
}
```

Json object I send

```
private val issuerEmail = "irfan*********@gmail.com"
private val issuerId = "338800000002212****"
private val passClass = "338800000002212****.e7504e23-****-4852-b8e4-9345684a2e06"
private val passId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

private val newObjectJson = """
{
  "iss": "$issuerEmail",
  "aud": "google",
  "typ": "savetowallet",
  "iat": ${Date().time / 1000L},
  "origins": [],
  "payload": {
    "genericObjects": [
      {
        "id": "$issuerId.$passId",
        "classId": "$passClass",
        "genericType": "GENERIC_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
        "hexBackgroundColor": "#4285f4",
        "logo": {
          "sourceUri": {
            "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/pass_google_logo.jpg"
          }
        },
        "cardTitle": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Google I/O '22  [DEMO ONLY]"
          }
        },
        "subheader": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Attendee"
          }
        },
        "header": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Alex McJacobs"
          }
        },
        "barcode": {
          "type": "QR_CODE",
          "value": "$passId"
        },
        "heroImage": {
          "sourceUri": {
            "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/google-io-hero-demo-only.jpg"
          }
        },
        "textModulesData": [
          {
            "header": "POINTS",
            "body": "${Random.nextInt(0, 9999)}",
            "id": "points"
          },
          {
            "header": "CONTACTS",
            "body": "${Random.nextInt(1, 99)}",
            "id": "contacts"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
"""
```

Due to the fact that I am in India, is it not working for me?

Answer (score 1):

Google Wallet is currently [not available in India](https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/12060037?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-vaccine-cards-test-records%2Cuse-google-wallet) as you suggested which is the reason why you are running into this issue.

Would love to know if you found a workaround for testing the API though!